# AutoMapper: How to do simple flattening

Tags: automapper

I need:

```
// SOURCE
class A { 
  public B B;
  public C C;
}

class B { public int X; }
class C { public int Y; }

// DESTINATION
class D { 
  public int X; 
  public int Y;
}

// I want to configure following operation
// without mapping each (X and Y) fields explicitly.
D.X = A.B.X;
D.Y = A.C.Y;


// here is the essence of what I am trying to accomplish.
Mapper.CreateMap<B, D>();
Mapper.CreateMap<C, D>();
var map = Mapper.CreateMap<A, D>();
map.ForMember(dst => dst, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.B));
map.ForMember(dst => dst, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.C));
```

Any suggestions?

Note: I am aware that if I change D.X to D.BX and D.Y to D.CY it will work. I want to accomplish this without prefixing D's properties. I also can accomplish this by using "Fill" version of the Map.

Answer (score 0):

```
// I want to configure following operation
// without mapping each (X and Y) fields explicitly.
D.X = A.B.X;
D.Y = A.B.Y;
```

According to your class, B does not have a Y. B has an X. Did you mean `D.Y = A.C.Y`? If so:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<A, D>()
    .ForMember(d => d.X, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.B.X))
    .ForMember(d => d.Y, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.C.Y))
;
```

Comment: Yes, that will do it. I have many fields and I don't want to map them explicitly. I did say 'without mapping each (X and Y) fields explicitly' in the question.

Comment: Yes, I did mean A.C.Y, not A.B.Y. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: You did say that, for some reason I thought you meant without having the `CreateMap<B, D>` and `CreateMap<C, D>` lines (which shouldn't be necessary to flatten). It seems to me like you already know the same options I would offer, either renaming the properties in D or mapping each property explicitly using ForMember. I can't think of any other way to do it, so I'd be happy to delete my answer if you'd like, just let me know.